# Formulário não passa valor atribuído a variáveis com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu crio duas variáveis globais e gostaria que ao enviar o formulário determinado valor de um input atribuísse a uma das variáveis e a outra como foi setada como false, recebesse true.

```
var escolhaPlayer1 = "";

var player1pronto = false;

$(document).ready( () =>{

    $('#form1').on('submit', (event) => {

        event.preventDefault();

        escolhaPlayer1 = $("#form1 input[type=radio]:checked").val();

        player1pronto = true;

    });

    console.log(escolhaPlayer1);
    console.log(player1pronto);

})
```

Mas o que acontece é o seguinte, quando chamo essas variáveis depois, os valores que foram atribuídos dentro do formulário não são atualizados, e mostra os valores que foram setados na criação delas.

Se eu colocar o `console.log()` dentro do formulário para mostrar o valor, ele pega, agora quando coloco fora não vem o valor atribuído.

Gostaria de saber como faço para receber esses valores do formulário em variáveis globais.

**OBS:** Já tentei passar com `data()` e `localStorage()`, deu em nada. A única diferença foi que com o `localStorage()` o valor mostra, mas apenas depois que atualizar a página.

Comment: mas você não está submentendo o formulário? isso recarrega a página e consequentemente reinicializa as variáveis

Comment: Acho que entendi, mesmo assim preciso que o formulário passe esses valores sem atualizar, tem como ?

Comment: Com o `event.preventDefault();` a página ainda assim reinicia?

Comment: Não reinicia, porquê ele impede isso. Aí talvez não chega a passar o valor para a variável. Aí onde entra a questão que se for esse caso, teria como fazer isso de alguma outra maneira?

Comment: Não acho que esse seja o problema, mesmo com o event.preventDefault(); os valores são atribuidos às variáveis.

Comment: Entendi, então tenho que dar o jeito no código para poder fazer isso de outra forma.

Comment: Não é uma boa usar variáveis globais, tente declarar como `let escolhaPlayer1` dentro do `(document).ready` e atribuir os valores usando `this.escolhaPlayer1`. Me avise se funcionar.

Comment: Nada... O que eu estou tentando fazer é o seguinte: É um joguinho simple de jokenpô  para praticar o jQuery. O player 1 e o 2 tem seus formulários que envia suas escolhas entre pedra, papel e tesoura, aí é onde quando eles escolherem eu pegar o escolhaPlayer1 = (que vem a opção escolhida) e player1pronto = (ver se ele clicou no botão pra escolher). E depois trabalho com os dados...